# How do you know when the dot operator is being used to reference a field or to perform a relational join in Alloy?

Tags: alloy, formal-languages

I am confused about the dot operator in Alloy (the formal modelling language). Sometimes it seems that when I perform the relational join I get the expected output however sometimes I feel it is being used just to access a field of the sig and the relational join would not work/just give an empty set.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered here: [Relational Join and Operators in Alloy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253014/relational-join-and-operators-in-alloy)

If, after reading the given links, you still have difficulties to understand the way dot joins work on a particular example, please edit your question to include the said example so that we can help you clarify their behavior.